# Which AMD display driver to install?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I just fresh-installed Ubuntu 15.04 and I went to "Software Center" > "Additional Drivers" to install the driver for my card (AMD 5570 1GB).

But I found 3 "Sources" and I don't know which one to choose. [see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKl8V.png)

Or should I use this? [Ubuntu AMD Catalyst Install](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uaci/)

I'm concerned about installing the driver because I have some minor graphic "glitches". (I can't add photos or more than two links so I can't show you a example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second or third options. `fglrx` driver is the stable version of AMD's proprietary driver. `fglrx-updates` driver will be possibly less stable, but will get you driver updates sooner. Either is better than the open source Xorg driver.

Comment: Then I think I'll stick with fglrx. thanks! @mkasberg